# PHP Get image from whatsapp conversation cloud api

Tags: php, cloud, whatsapp

To download an image received from the webhook, first, I retrieve the URL with the call to the media endpoint, I execute a curl call to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

where xxxxxxxxxxxxxx is the media id.

The code I use to do that is:

```php
$token = 'sdfsfsdfd';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/xxxxx',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$token,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));
 
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response."<hr>";

$dati = json_decode($response);
```

and the `$response` is:

```
(
    [url] => https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/whatsapp_business/attachments/?mid=790316572396xxx&ext=1659596318&hash=ATuHn61BbJOBYzugyRcP6O6UnyY2NSVh3Bb8v12OS3OCzQ
    [mime_type] => image/jpeg
    [sha256] => 1cf4a54f0d86c6603d10ad2e9836bc5a98edfabab4b5b8120822be59cbdcxxx0
    [file_size] => 253685
    [id] => xxxxx
    [messaging_product] => whatsapp
)
```

After this, I make a new curl call to the obtained URL

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $dati->url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$token
    
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
}

$getstatusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if($getstatusCode == 200){
    
    echo 'Downloaded!<hr>';
        
    echo $response;
    
} else{
    
    echo "Status Code: " . $getstatusCode;
    
}
```

But the `$response` obtained is the "something went wrong".

I would have expected a binary blob instead.

Where did I go wrong?

Please note, this issue is in Whatsapp Cloud API not the business API.

Comment: When I visit that URL in my browser, it asks my consent for setting cookies first, and then it wants me to log in. Are these download URLs meant for automated tools, or are they maybe only supposed to be used by actual users?

Comment: I'm also same problem. I can't access any attachment.

Comment: Can you knock me? We are both trying to working with whats app API which can be help us.

Comment: @AbdusSalam , did u get the answer for this? kindly give the solution or this

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue of getting an error with browser and changed the User-Agent within the header to a postman like one: User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.34.0
And it worked
Just for future readers (or me if I forget it)